# JAXB with inheritance but without using child element names

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I am working with XML from a vendor system that I cannot change and I am trying to use JAXB with it.  The XML is used in a REST like API.  See below for a couple message examples.  Each request/message has the same root element name that is called MsgRequest and it contains a couple common elements that are in every request but it also contains elements that are dependent on the message type.

```
<!-- request 1 -->
<MsgRequest>
  <SubType>GetUser</SubType>
  <RequestID>1</RequestID>
  <UserName>joe</UserName>
</MsgRequest>

<!-- request 2 -->
<MsgRequest>
  <SubType>GetCompany</SubType>
  <RequestID>2</RequestID>
  <CompanyName>joe</CompanyName>
</MsgRequest>
```

From Java perspective I could model it like this using inheritance.

```
class BaseMessage {
  String subType;
  Integer requestID;
};

class GetUserMessage {
  String userName;
};

class GetCompanyMessage {
  String companyName;
};
```

I don't understand how I would use JAXB to represent this XML.  I have done some research and found XMLElementRef but that will marshal the name of the referenced element which is not what I want.

Hopefully I am missing something obvious.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

XML wasn't designed to fit any particular language or even paradigm. This means thatbut you can design an XML that can be represented by a Java class hierarchy but there's no guarantee that some XML structure that comes your way can be mapped to a class hierarchy. Consider that an XML parser must be able to determine the (complex) type of an XML element from the element's tag name. So, if you have two elements tagged `<MsgRequest>`, they'll have to be mapped to a single Java type.

You can write an XML Schema for a single complex type with required fields subType and requestID, and optional (minOccurs=0) fields userName and companyName. It won't be good OO style, but it'll generate your XML.